# SQL Server ANSI_Padding

Tags: sql-server

If I right click on a table in SQL Server Management Studio and select 'Script table as > Create to > New Query Editor Window' the code that appears contains:

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

.... create the table ...

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF

So, I guess, whether ANSI_Padding is on or off affects the whole database and it is turned on to create a table and then turned off again?

What happens if you create a table with ANSI_Padding off? How can you turn it on for that table?

Comment: late comment, but I want to share my findings when searching for related topic http://sqlmag.com/blog/sql-server-management-studio-s-ugly-ansipadding-bug

Comment: http://www.sqlines.com/sql-server/ansi_padding

Answer (score 14):

> [SET ANSI_PADDING](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx) Controls the way
>   the column stores values shorter than
>   the defined size of the column, and
>   the way the column stores values that
>   have trailing blanks in `char`, `varchar`,
>   `binary`, and `varbinary` data.
>
> **In a future version** of MicrosoftSQL Server ANSI_PADDING will
>   always be ON and any applications that
>   explicitly set the option to OFF will
>   produce an error. Avoid using this
>   feature in new development work, and
>   plan to modify applications that
>   currently use this feature.

This setting affects only the definition of *new* columns. After the column is created, SQL Server stores the values based on the setting when the column was created. *Existing columns are not affected by a later change to this setting.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm puzzled. On the one hand you are saying this only affects the definition of new columns - whereas the anser above says it affects how data in whole tables is retrieved?

Comment: @MikeWilson: Both answers are correct. The quoted text above is slightly misleading in that it is referring to the use of SET ANSI_PADDING in DDL rather than DML.

Comment: So, if ANSI_Padding should be on, should I ...
when I select 'Script table as > Create to > New Query Editor Window' and the code that appears contains:

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

.... create the table ...

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF

... delete 'SET ANSI_PADDING OFF'? Why does SQL Server generate SET ANSI_PADDING OFF' if it should always be on? I'm using 2008 by the way.

Comment: "delete 'SET ANSI_PADDING OFF'?" Yes you should IMHO. We've had situations where those mechanically generated scripts have been run, and the session was then in the "OFF" state, and something else was run (with the OFF state) which then caused a conflict later on. The scripts SSMS generates tend to finish with SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF which is similarly bad news.

Answer (score 6):

> So, I guess, whether ANSI_Padding is on or off affects the whole database and it is turned on to create a table and then turned off again?

no, the SET option only affects the context of your connection, if 2 connections come in and one has ANSI_PADDING OFF and the other one ON they don't affect the other connection. However....the table created in one connection will have the behavior that the setting did to it.

read more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx

So if connection 1 comes in with set ansi_nulls off
then `select * from bla where col = null` will work

this however won't work for connection 2 if it comes with with the default ansi_nulls setting (ON)

you can see what you settings are by either executing `dbcc useroptions` or if you are on 2005 and up

```
SELECT SPID,VALUE,ANSI_SETTING
FROM (
SELECT @@SPID AS SPID,
CASE quoted_identifier
WHEN 1 THEN 'SET' ELSE 'OFF' END QUOTED_IDENTIFIER,
CASE arithabort
WHEN 1 THEN 'SET' ELSE 'OFF' END ARITHABORT,
CASE ansi_null_dflt_on
WHEN 1 THEN 'SET' ELSE 'OFF' END ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON,
CASE ansi_defaults
WHEN 1 THEN 'SET' ELSE 'OFF' END ANSI_DEFAULTS ,
CASE ansi_warnings
WHEN 1 THEN 'SET' ELSE 'OFF' END ANSI_WARNINGS,
CASE ansi_padding
WHEN 1 THEN 'SET' ELSE 'OFF' END ANSI_PADDING,
CASE ansi_nulls
WHEN 1 THEN 'SET' ELSE 'OFF' END ANSI_NULLS,
CASE concat_null_yields_null
WHEN 1 THEN 'SET' ELSE 'OFF' END CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE session_id = @@SPID ) P
UNPIVOT (VALUE FOR ANSI_SETTING IN(
QUOTED_IDENTIFIER,ARITHABORT,ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON,
ANSI_DEFAULTS,ANSI_WARNINGS,
ANSI_PADDING,ANSI_NULLS,CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL
)
) AS unpvt
```